# Unlink omniauth provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm building a simple authentication system that will allow multiple providers for a single user. I'm using [`omniauth`](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) and [`devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). Is there a way to unlink a particular provider for a single user from my application?

By unlinking provider I mean removing the user from oauth application and removing data (uid and things like that) about this particular provider (Facebook, Twitter) from my database. That is, the user will not be able to sign in using Facebook, for example, anymore after unlinking.

I've already checked [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking) and it does not helper too much. I've also checked out `devise` and `omniauth` docs. It seems that there's no built in way of achieving this. Do I have to make requests by myself to each provider in order to unlink an `OAuth` token?

Comment: What do you mean by "*unlink a provider*"?

Comment: @Uzbekjon I've updated description.

Comment: You would just remove the row(s) in whatever table you are using to store the OAuth details  such as`user.authentications.find_by(provider: 'facebook').destroy`. Facebook also has an API endpoint for revoking app permissions. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, OmniAuth and Devise do not have this "feature" built-in. You would have to implement it as a separate controller, that would manage user providers.

Comment: And I would have to make API calls by myself to each OAuth provider that will revoke authorization?

Comment: I see, you want to revoke authentication on provider as well. Yeap, you need to do that yourself. But, it is easy. Usually, it is a matter of making `DELETE` HTTP request, since most of the providers provide restful oauth service. Here is a [FB example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking#revokelogin).

Comment: I got it. Thank you.